# How to preload data before main

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

My goal is to quickly deal with various race conditions that can cause problems if a given function is called in 2 separate threads around the same time. My quick-fix is to just guarantee the functions have been initialized by calling them before main(). This is the solution I've come up with, but I feel I'm likely re-inventing the wheel. Is there an already-available option in the MSVC2010 STL? (no boost, yet) Or is there perhaps a better way to quickly deal with these issues without having to add significant thread safety code to each function in this situation?

```
template <typename T, T func>
struct PreLoaderHelper
{
    PreLoaderHelper()
    {
        wcout << L"Preload helper constructor" << endl;
        func();
    }
};

template <typename T, T func>
struct PreLoader
{
    static PreLoaderHelper<T, func> _helper;
};

template <typename T, T func>
PreLoaderHelper<T, func> PreLoader<T, func>::_helper;

#define PRELOAD(fn) template struct PreLoader<decltype(&fn), fn>; 

void foo() { wcout << L"inside foo" << endl; }
void bar() { wcout << L"inside bar" << endl; }
vector<wstring> & foobar() 
{ 
    static vector<wstring> sPresidents;
    if(sPresidents.size() == 0)
    {
        sPresidents.push_back(L"George Washington");
        sPresidents.push_back(L"John Addams");
        sPresidents.push_back(L"Thomas Jefferson");
    }
    return sPresidents;
}
wstring foofoo(const wstring &) { wcout << L"inside foofoo" << endl; return L"foofoo";}

PRELOAD(foo);
PRELOAD(bar);
PRELOAD(foobar);
PRELOAD(foo);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Programming is really awesome, everyone thinks completely different. Can you explain why not use a mutex ?

Comment: Does MSVC2010 support [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)? However, I always get suspicious if I see concurrent code with access to the same data not using a mutex or atomics. Also, we can see your solution, but not your actual problem. Your solution is better off at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Speed mostly, both to write and execute. It would take me longer to create a host of mutexes (one per function) and add the locking in for each. Also, by locking a mutex everytime I call a particular function, it is going to take significantly longer to execute. I could fix this with a double-checked locking implementation, but that is a lot more effort per-function to implement correctly for my chosen platform. @Zeta, I'll update a bit

Comment: Would calling `PRELOAD` avoid *given function is called in 2 separate threads around the same time*?

Comment: @KenKin yep - this causes the function to be called once as part of a constructor of a global (static) object; since such objects are initialized before main, it should guarantee we won't hit the race condition, unless another similar construct somewhere kicks off a thread in the same way.

Comment: If the threads are started in `main()`, isn't it better to put `PRELOAD` at the begin of `main()`? Or if the threas are not started in `main()`, could you describe for more details of your situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question: do you really have to call them before
entering main?  Why not just call them the first thing in main,
before starting any threads?

Otherwise: the classical idiom is to use them in an initializer
to a static variable.  The usual way is to call them from a
constructor; if you have additional data which must be
initialized, this is doubtlessly the best way.  If not,
something as simple as:

```
static bool initialized = (function(), true);
```

will do the trick.

Formally, this only guarantees that they will be initialized
before anything else in the same translation unit has been used,
but practically, this will guarantee that the function is called
before main, or during the loading of the DLL, if it is in a DLL
other than the one with main.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I came up with, but in a way that I don't need to pollute any namespace with a bunch of additional variables names (or expect a global 'initialized' variable to be externally defined). As for why not call in main, I like the idea of keeping this logic next to the function, so someone looking at the code later won't wonder 'well what if 2 of my threads are trying to initialize together?'

Comment: @Rollie If you're really worried about polluting some namespace, create a special namespace just for each initialization.  (`namespace STRCONCAT( ForInitialization, __LINE__ )` in an anonymous namespace, if you're really paranoid.)  IMHO, either making it static or putting it in an anonymous namespace should be sufficient.

Comment: @Rollie And finally: such initialization is often related to a specific class.  If so, using a private static member variable of the class will keep the name as private as you could possible want.

Comment: @LokiAstari You can't protect against every possible stupidity.

Comment: They will always be building better idiots. I considered the STRCONCAT solution, i tend to shy away from that sort of thing. Plus, the template solution prevents multiple initialization of the same function. Still, good points in your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
int dummy = (foo(), (void)0, bar(), 0);

int main() 
{
    // foo() and bar() have already been called
}
```

Furthermore, C++11 guarantees that the following variant causes only one single call, race-free:

```
void call_foo()
{
    static int dummy = (call_foo(), 0);
}

void some_thread_function() { call_foo(); }
```

Comment: Ohhh, nice use of comma operator. VC10 is not quite as compliant as I'd like, so I don't think your 2nd part part will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++11 then remember that:

1. static function variable initialization is thread safe.
2. You can use list initialization semantics.

Try:

```
std::vector<std::wstring>& plop1()
{
    // Thread safe
    // Guaranteed to be done once
    // No setup required
    // No cost if not used.
    static std::vector<std::wstring> sPresidents =
    {   
        L"George Washington",
        L"John Addams",
        L"Thomas Jefferson"
    };  
    return sPresidents;
}
```

Comment: Oh how I wish this was possible...tried to fight that fight a few times, unsuccessfully. And VC11 has added quite a few other good features with the most recent patch

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using proper synchronization using critical sections for your situation. Entering and exiting critical sections does not add a lot of code and handles the situation gracefully.

In case you do not want to continue with your original approach of initializing functions before main(), you can use global variable initialization as it occurs prior to main function call. There is a  nice article about this approach at

http://blog.fishingcactus.com/index.php/2009/01/28/fixing-c-static-and-global-variable-initialization/#sthash.pmBtrYD8.dpbs